# Minus value from array value?

Tags: php

I have the following

```
$interests_row['coff']
```

which displays "23" for example, is it possible you can minus 1 from an array value? such as...

```
 $interests_row['coff' - 1]
```

Comment: In order to solve what problem?

Answer (score 2):

You're altering the index value not the value itself.  You can do it at least these two ways:

```
$interests_row['coff'] -= 1;
```

or

```
$interests_row['coff'] = $interests_row['coff'] - 1;
```

Comment: This stops my page from display? Im trying... print "sentance here".$interests_row['coff'];

Comment: Try `$interests_row['coff']--` or `--$interests_row['coff']`.

Comment: There's no indication that he wants to _modify_ the stored value.

Answer (score 0):

Nope you need to do:

```
$interests_row['coff'] -1;
```

If you use a variable as key something like that would be possible but not in your usecase:

```
$key = 23;
$interests_row[$key -1];
```

If you want to modify the value the key is referencing to:

```
$interests_row['coff] = $interests_row['coff] - 1;
$interests_row['coff] = "test";
etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to subtract from the value `$interests_row['coff']`?

OK, well just do that then:

```
$interests_row['coff'] - 1
```

Depending on the surrounding code, you may want to use parentheses to group the expression:

```
($interests_row['coff'] - 1)
```